# Como passar parâmetros do VB6 para Crystal 9

Tags: visual-basic-6

A princípio quero deixar a nota que não é a minha praia vb e cristal, também tive enormes dificuldades em identificar as versões dos programas usados para dar manutenção a esse sistema. Mas no mais, já faz alguns anos que raramente tenho que mexer nele e normalmente apanho um pouco mas faço o que tem que ser feio.

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

- Banco de dados Sql Server 2000.
- O sistema é desenvolvido no velho vb6 "Jesus".
- E tem alguns relatórios desenvolvidos em crystal.

A priore instalei o crystal 8.5 e consegui editar os relatórios, e foi tudo OK até então.

Porém precisei criar um novo relatório e não descobri como criar um relatório usando procedures no crystal 8.5, e foi ai que me perdi. 
Instalei o crystal 9 nele eu criei o relatório novo e atualizeis os demais para usarem a nova biblioteca do crystal.
No crystal os relatórios funcionam bem, no VB também porem quando executo sou solicitado a passar os parâmetros, sendo que isso é feito pelo sistema, para o relatório funcionar. Já quebrei a cabeça, e nada que eu tenha feito foi eficaz para resolver o problema.

Segue o código para ver se alguém possa me ajudar.

```
Private Sub btn_boleto_Click()
    If Trim(Me.COD_HISTORICO1.Caption) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Selecione uma cobrança para imprimir o boleto.", vbInformation, "Atenção"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim STR_STATUS As String

    With Me.Relatorio

        .Connect = "UID=sa;PWD=#######;DRIVER={MICROSOFT ODBC FOR SQLSERVER};SERVER=(local)"
        .ReportFileName = App.Path & "\Relatorios\Boleto.rpt"

        .CopiesToPrinter = 1
        .DiscardSavedData = True
        .WindowBorderStyle = crptSizable

        .WindowTitle = "Alsite - Boleto"

        .WindowControlBox = True
        .WindowState = crptMaximized

        .RetrieveStoredProcParams
        .StoredProcParam(0) = "45"

        .Destination = crptToWindow
        .Action = 1

    End With
End Sub

o grande problema está nas linhas:

        .RetrieveStoredProcParams
        .StoredProcParam(0) = "45"

*já tirei a primeira
*já mudei a segunda

StoredProcParam("@Nome_parametro") = 45

ParameterFields(0).AddCurrentValue 45

ParameterFields(0).AddCurrentValue = 45

ParameterFields("@Nome_parametro").AddCurrentValue 45
ParameterFields("@Nome_parametro").AddCurrentValue = 45

ParameterFields(0) = "@Nome_parametro;45;TRUE"
```

e assim por diante...

Answer (score 0):

Esta é a forma que eu uso para meus relatórios em Crystal XI.

Talvez sirva:
(Os tipos usados foram para exemplificar)

```
Public Sub GerarRelatorio(sku As String, ativo as Integer)
    'CRRelatorio é o design (ICRDesign) do Crystal    
    CRRelatorio.RecordSelectionFormula = "{produto.sku} ='" & sku & "' AND {produto.tipo} = " & status

    'CRViewer1 é o objeto CrystalActiveXReportViewer que inserimos dentro de um form.
    CRViewer1.ReportSource = CRRelatorio
    CRViewer1.ViewReport
      
    DoEvents
    
    Me.Show vbModal
    CRViewer1.Refresh
End Sub
```